# Android Camera capture full image and send to PHP on server

Tags: java, php, android, android-camera

I can use camera capture of images on iPhone and send to PHP and this works fine. However, I have run into issues trying to do the same on Android.

I will provide code below but here is the logic. I use `FileProvider` in the `Activity`, `manifest.xml` and then in a `Fragment`. I create an image file `Uri` and then an intent for new `Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)`.

In the `onActivityResult` I use the `Uri` of file to get a `Bitmap`. I use `compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,70,stream)` to get a jpeg in a  `ByteArrayOutputStream()`.

I then attach this  `ByteArrayOutputStream()` to text using `toString` and send it to PHP on server using a `HttpURLConnection` and `BufferedWriter`.

In the PHP I detach the jpeg from the text using `substr` and save to a file and it says `JIFI` in beginning  but the file is not a valid jpeg. Using `getimagesize` returns null.

While I am sure this should be done `multipart`, but doing this on iPhone works fine. I don't think what I am doing on PHP is wrong. I suspect I am not sending the right form of image to PHP.

When I encode before sending in Android it looks like an encoded jpeg.

Here is the code. I have not posted in a very long time so please be patient and kind.

This is the File Provider

```
     <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.afs.genapp"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

This is Intent and I know I have issue with requesting permission

```java
 private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
   if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)  {          
         // Create the File where the photo should go
            photoFile = null;
         try {
             photoFile = createImageFile();
         } catch (IOException ex) {
             // Error occurred while creating the File
         }

         // Continue only if the File was successfully created
         if (photoFile != null) {
             photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                     "com.afs.genapp",
                     photoFile);



             if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                     context,
                     Manifest.permission.CAMERA
             ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
             ) {
                 // permission granted;
             } else {
                 // permission not granted
             }

             int ALL_PERMISSIONS = 101;
             final String[] permissions = new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

             final String[] requestPermissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

         if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),permissions, ALL_PERMISSIONS);
         }

             if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),requestPermissions, ALL_PERMISSIONS);
             }


             takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            // startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
             startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is the onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    switch(requestCode) {


        case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:

            IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(resultCode, data);

            if (result.getContents() != null) {
                System.out.println("Into afsConfigure 1" + result.toString());

                scanView.QF.setText(result.getContents());
            } else {
                scanView.QF.setText("Click Above to Scan");
            }

            break;

        case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:


            System.out.println("Into  REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE");

          //  if (resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK && data!=null)
            if (resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
          


                try {
              //  Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                  // file = new File(currentPhotoPath);

                    Bitmap bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), photoURI);
                  
                    // initialize byte stream
                    //ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,70,stream);

                    sImage = stream.toString();
                    camView.CF.setText("Success");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }

                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }


            break;
    }


}
```

Here is how I attach it to the text:

```
if(sImage!= null)
        passit += sImage;
```

This is the Http

```
 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... Strings) {


            try {
             
                URL urlObj = new URL(Strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
              
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "image/jpeg");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

            
                BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));
           


                wr.write(passit);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
           
               conn.connect();

                System.out.println("Response" + conn.getResponseMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
               

            }

            return "done";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should not use an intermediate bitmap to begin with. And you should not use a -buffered- writer to upload non text. Writers are for text.

Comment: Thank you for responding. So you are saying to just get the saved file and not use the bitmap and then upload that using a different upload method?

Comment: Thanks again and I changed to DataOutputStream which works. I kept the Bitmap and compression because sizes of images  too large  and its just for capturing photo of hard copy like receipts. I also encoded before sending and decoding on php side. I will have to change php but better than before. As I said I am new to Stack, but will try to give you credit.